# how can we use "literally"?

Tags: adverbs, american-english, word-meaning

What does *literally* exactly mean?

I am not so clear about its meaning, and I often get confused.

Comment: You might want to read through these two meta questions: [How to ask about confusion between two words](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/382), and [How to ask questions that are answerable via a dictionary](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/466). I also like to point users to the exemplary questions asked by Yoichi on ELU, such as this [What does this mean](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103507) question, and this [What is the difference](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63039) question. Note the ample prior research, and the high upvote totals.

Comment: In other words, explain a little more about **what you already know**, and **why** you are confused, and I'll gladly reopen this question. (Heck, I might even upvote it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/literally?s=t) actually gives a very good description of what happened to the word literally and why there is confusion in it's definition and usage:

> Since the early 20th century, literally  has been widely used as an
>   intensifier meaning “in effect, virtually,” a sense that contradicts
>   the earlier meaning “actually, without exaggeration.” The use
>   is often criticized; nevertheless, it appears in all but the most
>   carefully edited writing.

Basically, what they are saying is that we are now using the word in two different ways. The traditional way of actual, concrete, black and white fact and to exaggerate something to make a point.

One of the examples they use for the second way is:

> The parties were literally trading horses in an effort to reach a
>   compromise.

In this case, "literally trading horses" refers to the huge amount of give and take that was going on.

Answer (score 0):

The NOAD has the following note about *literally*:

> In its standard use, *literally* means ‘in a literal sense, as opposed to a nonliteral or exaggerated sense’: "I told him I never wanted to see him again, but I didn't expect him to take it literally." In recent years, an extended use of *literally* (and also *literal*) has become very common, where *literally* (or *literal*) is used deliberately in nonliteral contexts, for added effect: "They bought the car and literally ran it into the ground." This use can lead to unintentional humorous effects ("we were literally killing ourselves laughing") and is not acceptable in formal English.

Comment: Even [CNN](http://www.cnn.com/2013/08/15/living/literally-definition/index.html) is weighing in on with references to various online dictionary sites.

Comment: @lonehorseend They don't mention that [this sense has been in the OED since 1903 and dates back to 1769](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/08/literally/).  That is, the recent years in question are not *all* that recent...